# How to extract a certain line of text in an email and set as variable

Tags: string, parsing, text, outlook, line

Is anyone able to tell me how to store the entire third line of an email (not very long, and will always be the third line only), as a string?

For example, the email body looks like:

> Hi Person,
>
> COMPANY
>
> Please enjoy this email...

I want to be able to save the 3rd line, COMPANY as a string to help automate saving of files.

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out!

```
Arr = Split(olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
MkDir defaultPath & sInput & " - " & Arr(2)
```